# TLS through CDN

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, cdn, gcp

I'm trying to understand how TLS is terminated between a client and an origin when a CDN is involved.

I think it's pretty straightforward when a client connects directly to an origin, a handshake can be established for any number of certs / SAN members associated with the origin server.

But what if I need the CDN?  Is it impossible to use a 3rd party CDN in front of my origin without uploading that same origin cert and configuring it to be presented from the CDN?

I know different CDNs handle things differently. For example, it seems that Google CDN is able to properly terminate TLS with certs applied to an upstream GCP LB.  Is that just a special thing that only GCDN is capable of because of their close integration in GCP?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to host my own certs at my own origin and just have the CDN pass-thru TCP directly to the origin so the client and the origin server can have end to end certification and encryption with zero additional config at the CDN while the CDN still does the caching part.  But sounds like that's just not possible?

`client => cdn => origin(cert)`

Comment: If a 'CDN' passes through TCP, and TLS, to your origin server, it (1) can't see and understand what was requested _or_ served and (2) can't save what is served and replay it to someone else, even if it could somehow guess that someone else is requesting the same thing, because the TLS encryption is session-specific. So this wouldn't 'distribute content' at all, and would cost a good deal of money while providing _negative_ benefit -- no improvement ever and additional delay always. No one wants or would pay for or implement that. ...

Comment: ... Cloudflare does offer an [intermediate option](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/keyless-ssl/) -- they configure and use your cert, but you _don't_ give them your privatekey, instead every TLS handshake by any of their edge nodes sends a (realtime) request to _your_ 'key server' to do the privatekey operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDN is nothing more than a load balancer on steroids. When client makes a request, then two different TLS sessions are established:

1. client -> CDN
2. CDN -> origin

This means that:

1. client needs to trust only CDN certificate
2. CDN must trust origin certificate if communication between CDN and origin use TLS. However, this TLS connection isn't required and if link between CDN and origin is unencrypted -- client has no idea about this.

That is, there is no real end-to-end encryption between client and origin, CDN is a TLS termination point. Whatever happens behind CDN is a black box for client. And you can't detect or avoid this on client side. CDN must have access to TLS-encrypted data to figure out what to do with the request, like search in local cache, route to closest origin and so on.

Comment: yep, that's pretty much what I thought. good answer, thanks for confirming.